# IOCTL Method - Linux

Tags: linux, ioctl

I have an exam question and I can't quite see how to solve it.
A driver that needs the `ioctl` method to be implemented and tested.

I have to write the `ioctl()` method, the associated test program as well as the common `IOCTL` definitions.
The `ioctl()` method should only handle one command. In this command, I need to transmit a data structure from user space to kernel space. 
Below is the structure shown:

```
struct data
{

     char label [10];

     int value;

}
```

- The driver must print the `IOCTL` command data, using `printk()`;
- Device name is `"/dev/mydevice"`

The test program must validate driver mode using an initialized data structure.

Hope there are some that can help
thanks in advance

My suggestion:

```
static int f_on_ioctl(struct inode *inode, struct file *file,  unsigned int cmd,
unsigned long arg)
{
     int ret;

    switch (cmd) 
    {
    case PASS_STRUCT:
            struct data pass_data;
            ret = copy_from_user(&pass_data, arg, sizeof(*pass_data));
            if(ret < 0) 
            {
                printk("PASS_STRUCT\n");
                return -1;
            }
            printk(KERN ALERT "Message PASS_STRUCT : %d and %c\n",pass_data.value, pass_data.label);
            break;

    default: 
            return ENOTTY;
}

return 0;
```

}

Definitions:
Common.h

```
#define SYSLED_IOC_MAGIC 'k'
#define PASS_STRUCT _IOW(SYSLED_IOC_MAGIC, 1, struct data)
```

The test program:

```
int main()
{
  int fd = open("/dev/mydevice", O_RDWR);

  data data_pass;
  data_pass.value = 2;
  data_pass.label = "hej";

  ioctl(fd, PASS_STRUCT, &data_pass); 

  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

Is this completely wrong??

Comment: You will get (better/any) help if you show what you've actually tried so far.  This is not a "do it for me" kind of a site.

Comment: Is the new version completely wrong??